# For Excel VBA, If B2 value did not change then A2 will keep same, If B2 is changed then A2 will increase by one

Tags: vba, excel

I need a VBA  for the whole column B and A says that

if Value of Cell B2 did not change then A2 value will be the same
if B2 value is changed then A2 value will increase by one

[image: See my example]

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to make VBA in Excel do this job for me 
The value of Column A depends on value of Column B , As long the value of B is same , the Value of A should be same, if value of B changed then Value A would be increased by one

Comment: So you want the value to increase as you go down Column B and the values change?

Comment: the value of A increased as the value of B change ...you are right Scott

Comment: You need to improve you question con some code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula.

Put your staring number in A1.

Put this in A2:

```
=IF(B2<>B1,A1+1,A1)
```

And copy down.

[image]